# Converting binary data to .doc file with the images inside it

Tags: c#, sql, .net, type-conversion, binary-data

I have binary data stored in database which I need to convert them back for backup purposes. Most of them are .doc files with images attached in document. My method to restore them is to write binary data to byte string and write those bytes to the file like mydoc.doc. The problem is, it works for txt files and it actually works for text part of .doc file as well. Since most of the .doc files contain jpeg attached, after conversion I get some readable text and random characters which I believe are there for picture attached in doc file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Note: Binary data is stored in image data type in database. Database contains file path and name (which doesn't exist now) and corresponding binary data stored in image type, so from path I can detect the file type that it was before... some of them are .txt (which I was able to convert perfectly), some of them are .doc (which is problem because of attahcmens inside it)

Here is my code:

```
string s = "D0CF11E0A1B11AE100000000000000000000";   // note: string is for example
            var bytes = GetBytesFromByteString(s).ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\temp\\test.doc", bytes);
```

Comment: do a google search on the following `c# convert binary data to image` have you tried that..? also show the code where you are trying to convert the binary data back to an image..

Comment: You need to show the code you use to write the binary data to files.

Comment: I have tried converting it to jpeg and txt: converting to txt works partially since it can't convert it to jpeg... and converting to jpeg doesn't work since it contains binary data for text as well

Comment: How is your data encoded in the database? if it is a simple BLOB, **don't** convert it to a string, just save it as raw bytes.

Comment: just backup your database. what you are proposing is not supportable.

Comment: updated the description: it is stored in image datatype

Comment: Oh my god! Who did that?

Comment: Mike Beeler, application using that database is third party software, and company im working for is not planning to use that software anymore... so dumping the database is not a choice for backup, we will need to convert it from binary data in the future as well if we backup the database itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .doc file is *not* a string or even a text or ASCII. It is a raw binary file format.
So if your database cell contains a BLOB (Binary Large Object) simply treat it as an array of bytes and write it out to a (binary) file. No conversions, no encodings, nothing.

---

**Edit**

Whoever designed this database, they designed to store all kinds of files as an **image** (in the sense of memory-dump-image) i.e. a series of raw bytes in a cell of type image.

You should treat these bytes exactly as mentioned above: A series of raw bytes.

Comment: updated the description: data stored in image datatype

Comment: But your db cell contains a .doc or what?

Comment: database contains file path and name (which doesn't exist now) and corresponding binary data stored in image type, so from path I can detect the file type that it was before... some of them are .txt (which I was able to convert perfectly), some of them are .doc (which is problem because of attahcmens inside it)

Comment: Please add this info to your question, gives everything a completely different meaning.

Comment: it is already in the description part... but I guess it is not clear enough, I will try to paraphrase it.

Comment: So you are saying it is impossible to convert it from image datatype? :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76384/discussion-between-user1722022-and-drkoch).